# Performance of getting last of each group in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation

## Preface

I'm currently working on writing aggregation pipelines for a server that queries the latest available data every time a client asks for it. This happens very often (think every second or so), and so I'm wondering if you might be able to help me optimize a pipeline I've been scratching my head over. I would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions.

---

## Problem

The pipeline is supposed to query the latest available entry for each `b` in the collection. The schema of this collection is shaped like so:

```js
{
  at: Date,
  a: String,
  b: String,
  value: Any,
}
```

My current pipeline is:

```js
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "a": {
        "$in": [
          "a001", "a002", "a003", "a004", "a005", "a006", "a007", "a008", "a009", "a010",
          "a011", "a012", "a013", "a014", "a015", "a016", "a017"
        ]
      },
      "b": { "$exists": true },
      "$and": [
        { "at": { "$gte": ISODate("2020-02-23T10:15:11.396Z") } },
        { "at": { "$lt": ISODate("2020-02-24T10:15:11.396Z") } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { "at": 1 } },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { "a": "$a", "b": "$b" },
      "values": {
        "$last": {
          "k": "$a",
          "v": { "at": "$at", "value": "$value" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.b",
      "entries": { "$push": "$values" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": false,
      "b": "$_id",
      "entries": { "$arrayToObject": "$entries" }
    }
  }
]
```

> The `at` condition is used to specify a range of dates within which to find the latest entries. Insertion order is unreliable - as in does not necessarily correspond to an ordered list of `at` values -, so `_id` is useless for me as far as I can tell.
>
> The `"b": { "$exists": true }` condition is alternatively also an array of strings matching on specific beacons, just like `a`.

An index is defined on the fields `a`, `b`, and `at`:

```js
{ at: 1, a: 1, b: 1 }
```

Now unfortunately, having **7 million records** as of now - and counting fast -, **just above half a million** of which match the filter, this query is starting to run really slow, usually in the range of **3 to 5 seconds**, which is of course not particularly optimal in a production environment.

Running the pipeline results in something like the following:

```js
[
  {
    "b": "b001",
    "entries": {
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b002",
    "entries": {
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b003",
    "entries": {
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T09:48:24.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:56:43.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b004",
    "entries": {
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b005",
    "entries": {
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:07.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:33:28.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b006",
    "entries": {
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T09:27:14.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b007",
    "entries": {
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:58:40.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b008",
    "entries": {
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T07:38:34.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b009",
    "entries": {
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:59:58.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b010",
    "entries": {
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:39:40.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b011",
    "entries": {
      "a005": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b012",
    "entries": {
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:59:50.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b013",
    "entries": {
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b014",
    "entries": {
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b015",
    "entries": {
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:12:24.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b016",
    "entries": {
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a005": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b017",
    "entries": {
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:45:28.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:14.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b018",
    "entries": {
      "a011": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:34:29.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:17.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:15.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a009": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:00.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a010": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b019",
    "entries": {
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:58:54.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b020",
    "entries": {
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a005": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b021",
    "entries": {
      "a012": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:41:54.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:10.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a005": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:59:28.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a013": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:47:21.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a008": { "at": "2020-02-24T09:09:47.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  },
  {
    "b": "b022",
    "entries": {
      "a001": { "at": "2020-02-24a00:59:50.000Z", "value": {} },
      "a005": { "at": "2020-02-24T11:00:08.000Z", "value": {} }
    }
  }
]
```

> There is a mismatch in dates in these results and the query/explanation because I captured it at a different time. It is not an error.

Explaining the pipeline results in the following:

```js
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "query": {
          "a": {
            "$in": [
              "a001", "a002", "a003", "a004", "a005", "a006", "a007", "a008", "a009", "a010",
              "a011", "a012", "a013", "a014", "a015", "a016", "a017"
            ]
          },
          "b": { "$exists": true },
          "$and": [
            { "at": { "$gte": ISODate("2020-02-23T10:15:11.396Z") } },
            { "at": { "$lt": ISODate("2020-02-24T10:15:11.396Z") } }
          ]
        },
        "sort": { "at": 1 },
        "fields": { "at": 1, "b": 1, "a": 1, "value": 1, "_id": 0 },
        "queryPlanner": {
          "plannerVersion": 1,
          "namespace": "database.collection",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
              { "at": { "$lt": ISODate("2020-02-24T10:15:11.396Z") } },
              { "at": { "$gte": ISODate("2020-02-23T10:15:11.396Z") } },
              { "b": { "$exists": true } },
              {
                "a": {
                  "$in": [
                    "a001", "a002", "a003", "a004", "a005", "a006", "a007", "a008", "a009", "a010",
                    "a011", "a012", "a013", "a014", "a015", "a016", "a017"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "queryHash": "EEAA11B5",
          "planCacheKey": "C2A53FFA",
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": { "b": { "$exists": true } },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern": { "at": 1, "a": 1, "b": 1 },
              "indexName": "at_1_a_1_b_1",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": { "at": [], "a": [], "b": [] },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "at": [ "[new Date(1582452911396), new Date(1582539311396))" ],
                "a": [
                  "[\"a001\", \"a001\"]",
                  "[\"a002\", \"a002\"]",
                  "[\"a003\", \"a003\"]",
                  "[\"a004\", \"a004\"]",
                  "[\"a005\", \"a005\"]",
                  "[\"a006\", \"a006\"]",
                  "[\"a007\", \"a007\"]",
                  "[\"a008\", \"a008\"]",
                  "[\"a009\", \"a009\"]",
                  "[\"a010\", \"a010\"]",
                  "[\"a011\", \"a011\"]",
                  "[\"a012\", \"a012\"]",
                  "[\"a013\", \"a013\"]",
                  "[\"a014\", \"a014\"]",
                  "[\"a015\", \"a015\"]",
                  "[\"a016\", \"a016\"]",
                  "[\"a017\", \"a017\"]"
                ],
                "b": [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ]
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        },
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 511710,
          "executionTimeMillis": 3410,
          "totalKeysExamined": 559174,
          "totalDocsExamined": 511710,
          "executionStages": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": { "b": { "$exists": true } },
            "nReturned": 511710,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 583,
            "works": 559174,
            "advanced": 511710,
            "needTime": 47463,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 4476,
            "restoreState": 4476,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "docsExamined": 511710,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "nReturned": 511710,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 334,
              "works": 559174,
              "advanced": 511710,
              "needTime": 47463,
              "needYield": 0,
              "saveState": 4476,
              "restoreState": 4476,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "keyPattern": { "at": 1, "a": 1, "b": 1 },
              "indexName": "at_1_a_1_b_1",
              "isMultiKey": false,
              "multiKeyPaths": { "at": [], "a": [], "b": [] },
              "isUnique": false,
              "isSparse": false,
              "isPartial": false,
              "indexVersion": 2,
              "direction": "forward",
              "indexBounds": {
                "at": [ "[new Date(1582452911396), new Date(1582539311396))" ],
                "a": [
                  "[\"a001\", \"a001\"]",
                  "[\"a002\", \"a002\"]",
                  "[\"a003\", \"a003\"]",
                  "[\"a004\", \"a004\"]",
                  "[\"a005\", \"a005\"]",
                  "[\"a006\", \"a006\"]",
                  "[\"a007\", \"a007\"]",
                  "[\"a008\", \"a008\"]",
                  "[\"a009\", \"a009\"]",
                  "[\"a010\", \"a010\"]",
                  "[\"a011\", \"a011\"]",
                  "[\"a012\", \"a012\"]",
                  "[\"a013\", \"a013\"]",
                  "[\"a014\", \"a014\"]",
                  "[\"a015\", \"a015\"]",
                  "[\"a016\", \"a016\"]",
                  "[\"a017\", \"a017\"]"
                ],
                "b": [ "[MinKey, MaxKey]" ]
              },
              "keysExamined": 559174,
              "seeks": 47464,
              "dupsTested": 0,
              "dupsDropped": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": { "a": "$a", "b": "$b" },
        "values": {
          "$last": {
            "k": "$a",
            "v": { "at": "$at", "value": "$value" }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.b",
        "entries": { "$push": "$values" }
      }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": false,
        "b": "$_id",
        "entries": { "$arrayToObject": [ "$entries" ] }
      }
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "host",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "4.2.3",
    "gitVersion": "6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

The following seem to be important:

- The **index** `at_1_a_1_b_1` **is used**. *Excellent.*
- The **sorting step** is **optimized out** by MongoDB. *Nice, smart, thank you.*
- The **execution time** (`executionTimeMillis`) is **3.41s**. *Less than stellar.*
- Total **keys examined** (`totalKeysExamined`) is **559174**. *I suppose there is no going around that. Indexes must be examined to determine whether they match the given filter.*
- Total **documents examined and returned** (`totalDocsExamined` and `nReturned`) are both **511710**. *This one I have absolutely no idea about. Why is it so high? Why does it actually need to examine and return all those documents when I only select the `$last` of each group? Strange, but perhaps normal.*

## Alternative

If you deem that the pipeline is as optimal as it can get - which I am honestly hoping is not the case, it might just be that the server is simply not powerful enough to run it at such high request rate. It has an [Intel Xeon X5670](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47920/intel-xeon-processor-x5670-12m-cache-2-93-ghz-6-40-gt-s-intel-qpi.html) and 32GB RAM. MongoDB's CPU usage goes well above 100% every time the pipeline is run.

Comment: Compared to simple queries, aggregation pipeline's performance in mongo is always abysmal. The perfect way around this is not to use it. For mongo, just denormalize. When you need the "latest data" often, then hold the latest data in a separate collection and update that with the newest object whenever you insert something new. Always keep in mind, that normalization is a relational concept.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @mtj! Unfortunately, the variables can differ greatly between runs (the date range and other filters as well), going as far back as the first entry in the collection, so I'm unsure how I could store only the required data unless I enforced a rule that disallowed querying anything older than a week or so, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Can you tell how much time it takes to run the query using the same data - with the first stage of the aggregation only ($match), _and_ first+second stages only ($match+$sort)?

Comment: The indexes in the aggregation query are utilized only for the `$match` and the `$sort` stages (only when the these stages come at the beginning of the pipeline). They do not apply to the `$group` or `$project` stages. About the _"documents examined and returned"_ from the query plan - the numbers are from the `$match` stage (that is the number of documents returned and passed to the following stage).